# Can google's firebase(Real-time database) work with a java desktop application?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to communicate my android application with java desktop application using real time database (Firebase).

Answer (score 6):

It **is** possible to create a Java desktop application that uses the Firebase Admin SDK for accessing the database and other features. The syntax is similar to what is used in Android apps.

But note that this uses the Admin SDK, which (as its name implies) gives users full, administrative access to the back-end. Depending on your use-case, that may not be what you want.

An alternative would be to have your JavaFX application talk to the Firebase Database's REST API, which is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start

Also see:

- [Can google's firebase work with a java desktop application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315549/can-googles-firebase-work-with-a-java-desktop-application).
- [Using Firebase Admin in a Java desktop application (using Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211457/using-firebase-admin-in-a-java-desktop-application-using-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can connect it.In firebase, database is stored in JSON format and you can communicate using java networking api like java.net and connect to firebase. Also, in your project, you need to use JSON api's inorder to process/manipulate json data from firebase.